# How to highlight text in cypress?

Tags: javascript, text, automated-tests, cypress

I want to do some text selection on a text document as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSatZ.png). The words "automatically translates those" are highlighted using right click and dragging from start to end. I want to perform the similar operation using cypress.
Can someone help me with it?

I have tried trigger mouseover using cypress but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please advise what element you are working with - I am interested to know if it's an editable element like input or textarea, or display element like div, span, p.

Comment: I want to select and highlight span all the elements present under the
element. After all the element under the mentioned tag are selected, we get a word "Santa" that is highlighted.

```
<div class="section-text">
    <span sid="0" ost="0">S</span>
    <span sid="0" ost="1">a</span>
    <span sid="0" ost="2">n</span>
    <span sid="0" ost="3">t</span>
    <span sid="0" ost="4">a</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange) in javascript that can allow you to implement it.

Roughly speaking, this is how it goes:

This HTML:

```html
<div class="section-text">
  <span sid="0" ost="0">S</span> 
  <span sid="0" ost="1">a</span>
  <span sid="0" ost="2">n</span> 
  <span sid="0" ost="3">t</span>
  <span sid="0" ost="4">a</span>
</div>
```

using this test

```js
function selectText($start, $end) {
  const range = document.createRange()
  range.setStart($start[0], 0)
  range.setEnd($end[0], 1)
  cy.window()
    .then(win => win.getSelection().addRange(range))
}

cy.get('span[ost="0"]').then($start => {
  cy.get('span[ost="4"]').then($end => {
    selectText($start, $end)
  })
})

cy.window()
  .then(win => win.getSelection().toString())
  .should('eq', 'S a n t a')
```

Note the text you get back has spaces between the letters, so that may cause you problems in a more complex example that already contains spaces. But you can step through the string and take every second character,

```js
cy.window()
  .then(win => win.getSelection().toString())
  .then(selection => [...selection].reduce((acc, s, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) acc += s
    return acc
  }, ''))
  .should('eq', 'Santa')
```

**Test log**

[image]

Comment: appreciate your comment. i tried with the way you mentioned but got this error: 

assertexpected '' to equal Santa 
AssertionError 
expected '' to equal 'Santa'

Comment: I've attached the test log to confirm it works. If you give some more details, I might be able to fix whatever bug you have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I appreciate your help. Here's ( https://ibb.co/4mDWpJd ) the screenshot of the report. I am surprised how is it working with you.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't give any clues - reduced to guessing, but is it the browser? Window methods are implemented internally by the browser so maybe that's the cause. My test was on chrome, and the docs ref is MDN so it should also be good on Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, that's outside the scope of cypress. You can customize it using the CSS style containing the things you want to highlight.

Comment: I think i could not explain my requirement correctly.
The idea is to drag the word from start to end to select it and then perform some operations. 
I do not want to change the colour using CSS, i rather want to do some text selection so that i can perform some operations on it. This is for one of the UI test automation i am working on.

Comment: I have edited the title of the post. I hope this explains better. Can you take a look at it?